# How do I access the web UI for Kubernetes clustered that were created via EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I need a URL and the web UI log in credentials for Kubernetes.  I created Kubernetes clusters in AWS with EKS.  I have API endpoint URLs for the clusters based on what I see in the EKS section of the web UI of AWS.  But when I go to them in a web browser, there is no prompt for a username or password.

I ran this command: "kubectl config view | grep http"

But when I go to those URLs I see "403 Forbidden" errors.

I expect a URL that would allow me to log in for the new Kubernetes clusters that I created.  What should I do to determine the URLs?  Hopefully the default credentials will be ascertainable.

Answer (score 1):

With EKS, the Kubernetes UI need to be deploy manually. You have a fully detailed [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html) on how to deploy Kubernetes UI in EKS.

Comment: I am having trouble following those directions.  In Step #3 "Connect to the Dashboard" there is a substep, also #3, that I do not know how to follow.  It says "Open the following link with a web browser to access the dashboard endpoint: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login"

localhost on my Windows laptop will resolve to 127.0.0.1.  The link will just say "Unable to connect" in the web browser.  How do I connect to the dashboard?

Comment: I tried to use curl commands from the Linux server.  I would get Forbidden or 404 errors.  None of my variations got anywhere.  I set up a reverse proxy server, but I do not know what the valid URL would be.